# Dynamoose - How to Query Two GSI on the same Key?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

I have a key in dynamo that has two Global Secondary Indexes with different range keys. Like this:

```
 const productSchema = new Schema(
  {
   productCategory: {
      type: String,
      index: [{
        global: true,
        rangeKey: 'serialNumberEnd',
        name: 'productCategory',
        throughput: { read: 1, write: 1 },
        project: ['quantity'],
      },
      {
        global: true,
        rangeKey: 'orderType',
        name: 'openOrders',
        throughput: { read: 1, write: 1 },
        project: true,
      }],
  },
  {
    throughput: { read: 1, write: 1 },
    useNativeBooleans: true,
    saveUnknown: true,
  },
);`
```

Trying to use the 'name' does not seem to be the answer.

```
Resource.query('openOrder').eq(id)
```

How am I supposed to distinguish between the two GSI's on the same Key in a resource when constructing a query?

EDIT - Added additional context to the schema, moved answer to the answer section

Answer (score 2):

In this case you don't want to be using the `name` property of the index. You want to be using the actual property to do this.

For example:

```
Resource.query('openOrder').eq(id)
.where('serialNumberEnd').lt(5)
```

I don't know your entire schema so it's not an exact match of what you want to do. But something like that should work.

You can also look at [this test in the source code](https://github.com/dynamoosejs/dynamoose/blob/698de0ac04e2835c43573d31ea8f228887f03123/test/Query.js#L628-L679) for an example of using multiple indexes on one property and querying.

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = await Product.query(
{
  hash: { productCategory: { eq: 'tags' } },
  range: { orderType: { eq: 'sale' } },
},
{ indexName: 'openOrders' },).exec();
```

I was a bit slow at getting to this syntax. Hope this helps someone else.

EDIT: A little cleaner syntax/more context to the schema

```
const result = await Product.query('productCategory', { indexName: 'openOrders' }).eq('tags')
.where('orderType').eq('purchase')
.exec();
```

I had no luck getting Dynamoose to recognize the correct index based on the Range found in a 'where' statement. The { indexName: 'value' } is needed.

Comment: The query() function expects only one arg